# C++ how to implement with template specilization or other manner?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I am implementing a Boundary Volumn Hierarchy structure, where the tree has a template like this:

```
template <typename Coordinate> 
class BoundingTree { /* ... */ }
```

The `Coordinate` can be `Vector2d`, `Vector3f` or any other arbitrary coordinate. To use this `BoundingTree` structure for collision detection, there should be an detection function:

```
template <typename Coordinate> 
template <typename RigidBody>
bool BoundingTree::collide(RigidBody const & body);
```

The `RigidBody` can be everything, e.g. `Cuboid3f`, `Circle2d`. And my implementation of this detection system is:

```
// BoundingTree.h
template <typename Coordinate>
class BoundingTree
{
public:
    BoundingTree() {}

    // collide function decleration
    template <typename RigidBody>
    bool collide(RigidBody const & obj);

};

// BoundingTree.cpp
// specilizations
template<typename Coordinate> template <typename RigidBody>
bool BoundingTree::collide(RigidBody const & obj)
{
    std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

template<> template<>
bool BoundingTree<Vector3f>::collide<Sphere3f>(Sphere3f const & d)
{
    std::cout << "Vector3f Sphere3f" << std::endl;
    return 1;
};

template<> template<>
bool BoundingTree<Vector3f>::collide<Cuboid3f>(Cuboid3f const & d)
{
    std::cout << "Vector3f Cuboid3f" << std::endl;
    return 1;
};
```

But I got an Error:

```
1>BoundingTree.cpp(6): error C2955: 'BoundingTree': use of class template requires template argument list
1>  BoundingTree.h(32): note: see declaration of 'BoundingTree'
1>BoundingTree.cpp(10): error C2244: 'BoundingTree::collide': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
1>  BoundingTree.cpp(6): note: see declaration of 'BoundingTree::collide'
```

How to solve this problem?

Is there any better manner to implement this collision detection system with arbitrary types?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is line 6 of BoundingTree.cpp in your post? `BoundingTree::collide` has two `template <typename ...>` clauses before it. This is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Apart of the syntax issue, you cannot, generally, split templates into header and source files. See: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do [is allowed](http://ideone.com/QsVLeQ) but you have a syntax error which is here:

```
template<typename Coordinate> template <typename RigidBody>
bool BoundingTree::collide(RigidBody const & obj)
                         ^
```

This is not a specialization so you must specify the template argument for the class, it should be

```
bool BoundingTree::collide<Coordinate>(...)
```

But I see that your code is split into header and source, this can create problem with non specialization of your code.

If a templated function is defined inside a source file but used in another translation unit, then the instantiations of the template won't be generated during compilation and you'll get linker errors.

This won't happen with full specializations, like

```
template<> template<>
bool BoundingTree<Vector3f>::collide<Sphere3f>(Sphere3f const & d)
```

But if you plan to have partial specializations then you will be forced to move everything in the header file or force the instantiation of the template in the source file that defines them, eg

```
template class BoundingTree<MyCoord>;
template bool BoundingTree<MyCoord>::collide<MyShape>(MyShape const& d);
```

Comment: I believe the correct syntax is actually: "template <typename Coordinate>
template <typename RigidBody> bool BoundingTree<Coordinate>::collide(RigidBody const & obj)", at least according to gcc 5.3.1

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: On clang 3.4 this compiles and executes correctly, but I'm too tired to open the standard right now.

Comment: @Jack with all these in one header file, I got an error of `one or more multiply defined symbols found` when multiple included. Did I make it wrong?

Comment: @Jack Oh I fixed it by making all template definitions and the specilization functions' declerations in the header, and put the specilization functions' definition in the cpp. There is no error then.